# Is there a static analysis tool which automatically checks for race conditions in Java projects?

Tags: java, multithreading, static-analysis, race-condition

Is there a static analysis tool which automatically checks for race conditions in Java projects? Preferably the one supporting Eclipse, Spring and Hibernate. Thanks

EDIT: I may need not necessarily a static analysis tool but maybe a tool which runs the java threads (at least JUnit) with different random speed and also can reproduce the same speed profile under debugger. So, almost any way of detecting race conditions would be helpful.

Comment: Please give people credit for their effort to help you and [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/160062) on your previous questions. You haven't accepted a single answer.

Answer (score 6):

[JLint](http://artho.com/jlint/index.shtml) can be used to detect race-conditions. IBM's [ConTest](https://www.research.ibm.com/haifa/projects/verification/contest/index.html) is designed to test concurrency issues, so have a look at that as well.

Comment: JLint website does not look serious. Therefore would you mind me asking did you try it yourself and did it work well for you?

Comment: JLINT is one of the best @user1081596. Dont jusge the book by the cover :)

Comment: JLint is as serious as having a name "user1081596" ;)  Jokes aside, the only reason it "doesn't look serious" is because the dude didn't bother with a website and is not hosting it under java.net or sourceforge...

Comment: http://jlint.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I'm with @user1081596 on this. If you want your stuff to be taken seriously, spend more than 5 minutes on your website!

Comment: I don't find any windows binary and I don't have the tooling to compile it.

Answer (score 4):

[ThreadSafe](http://www.contemplateltd.com/threadsafe) (http://www.contemplateltd.com/threadsafe, free trials available) does exactly what the question asks for, also covering Java concurrency defects other than race conditions.  See this [InfoQ article](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Java-Concurrency-Static-Analysis-with-ThreadSafe) for examples of concurrency errors it finds in open source applications including Apache JMeter and K9Mail.  See [Ivan Senic's blog](http://blog.novatec-gmbh.de/threadsafe-fast-way-discover-concurrency-problems/) for a user's opinion.

(Disclosure: ThreadSafe is a commercial tool, and I'm co-founder of Contemplate, the company that produces it.)

Comment: Is ThreadSafe abandoned? The latest version is from 20. March 2015.

Comment: ThreadSafe is not abandoned, but it is not currently under active development.

Answer (score 1):

Static analysis is a good thing, no doubt. But may I suggest not so static [JPF](http://javapathfinder.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: It would be nice if JPF was a little easier to use, though.

Comment: Documentation says JPF checks for deadlocks but does it check for race conditions?

Answer (score 1):

If you use eclipse you can use [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/), to check the code. If you want you can run it from the the command-line too or with a Swing interface.

Answer (score 1):

Coverity Static Analysis for Java flags race conditions, as well as possible deadlock and atomicity violations.

In addition Coverity has a Dynamic Analysis product which instruments your own tests and reports potential race conditions and deadlocks.  Note that running it on unit tests is usually not effective as their logic tends to be simpler than the types of interaction a complex application will have in production and it's more effective to run Dynamic analysis with your stress, load tests or even ad hoc testing.

Disclaimer: I used to work for Coverity.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the product personally, but I thought of [Corensic Jinx](http://www.corensic.com/Products.aspx) when you wrote that you are looking for "a tool which runs the Java threads (at least JUnit) with different random speed". According to Corensic's product description page, Jinx observes threading operations at the native OS thread level and "dynamically builds a set of potential interleavings (i.e., alternate eventualities, or execution scenarios, that will occur under some future set of conditions) that are most likely to result in concurrency faults, and quickly tests those execution paths to surface concurrency problems including deadlocks, race conditions, and atomicity violations."

This might be too low-level for an all-Java application, but [Corensic claims](http://www.prweb.com/releases/2010/08/prweb4412774.htm) to support Java and Microsoft .NET applications.

See [Using Jinx with Java](http://wiki.corensic.com/wiki/Jinx_--_Using_Jinx_with_Java)

Answer (score 0):

[AppDynamics](http://www.appdynamics.com/products-free-download.php) is a tool that gets attached to your JVM and provides information about memory usage of individual threads.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a tool called http://vmlens.com which can detect data races, especially write/write data races. It searches for memory fields which are accessed from different threads without synchronization.

So its not a static analysis tool but rather dynamic. To detect a data race a memory location must be accessed at least by two different threads.

Regards
Thomas